# Highcharts gauge incorrectly rendering label values

Tags: highcharts, gauge

I'm new to Highcharts and just working with the guage.

I have changed the max value to 24 and set the data value to 20.

```
$('#container-speed').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 24,
        title: {
            text: 'Test ABC'
        }
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [20],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">83% visited</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' visited'
        }
    }]

}));
```

However, the gauge is displaying with a max value of 40 and the gauge at 50% (20/40).

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czSHK.png)

I guess I'm making a silly mistake somewhere, I can't see what... any help would be much appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/fzsy2mhk/

Thanks,

Comment: Instead of setting your `tickAmount` to **1**, set your `tickInterval` to **24**. You'ev told it to make one tick, but didn't give it an interval, so it chose its own interval.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max) :

> If a tickAmount is set, the axis may be extended beyond the set max in order to reach the given number of ticks.

Thus you must delete the `tickamount` from `gaugeOptions`.

Since you enabled `labels` in `yAxis`, the gauge will have automatic labels in ticks. You can disable it using `enabled:false`, or tweak using the `step` option.

Working JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/earlvon_lapura/xd96ogm6/)